# Points on decision hyperplane

Tags: linear-algebra, pattern-recognition

I'm reading a chapter on linear classifiers, and the authors define the decision hyperplane as:

$$
g(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{x} + w_0 = 0
$$
They say that if $\mathbf{x}_1$ and $\mathbf{x}_2$ are points on the decision hyperplane, then:
$$
\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{x}_1 + w_0 = 0 \\
\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{x}_2 + w_0 = 0
$$
and:
$$
\mathbf{w}^T(\mathbf{x}_1 - \mathbf{x}_2) = 0
$$
They then write *the difference vector $\mathbf{x}_1 - \mathbf{x}_2$ lies on the decision hyperplane.* Here I am lost. If it were on the decision hyperplane, wouldn't it need to satisfy the original equation? Specifically:
$$
\mathbf{w}^T(\mathbf{x}_1 - \mathbf{x}_2) + w_0 = 0
$$

What am I missing?

Comment: My high-school math teacher used to say "The book is wrong" when she wrote something wrong on the blackboard... Apparently, I would say this also in this situation. Indeed, if $\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{x}_1 + w_0 = 0$ and $\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{x}_2 + w_0 = 0$, then $\mathbf{w}^T(\mathbf{x}_1 - \mathbf{x}_2) + w_0 = 0$ reduces that $w_0 = 0$... Read your book carefully, and report here your findings.

Comment: The difference vector only lies on the hyperplace if $w_0=0$. Otherwise, it is _parallel_ to the hyperplane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement as written is false for arbitrary $w_0$. Given
$$
\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{x}_1 + w_0 = 0 \\
\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{x}_2 + w_0 = 0
$$
it follows that $\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{x}_1=\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{x}_2=-w_0$, and hence that
$$\mathbf{w}^T(\mathbf{x}_1 - \mathbf{x}_2)
=\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{x}_1-\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{x}_2
=(-w_0)-(-w_0)= 0.
$$
So 
It is "obviously" true if and only if $w_0=0$. I would say you are not missing anything.

You'd be surprised how many errors slip through dozens of editions.